# application layout not supporting with smaller screen size tablet

Tags: android

I have created an application for 10" tablet and set the `layout` related to screen size but my application is not supported with 7" tablet though i design folder in `resource` as

`res/layout-w320dp`
`res/layout-w600dp`
`res/layout-w720dp`

so please tell me how to set with other screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
  res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
  res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
  res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

  res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
  res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
  res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

For further reference check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html